# Non-linear differential equation with tricky variable dependence

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

My problem regards solving a differential equation and can be reduced to the problem of finding $f(x)$ such that
$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dh}{df}$, with $h(f)$ a known function.

I have this list  of data, from which I define a function `myfun` via `Interpolation` and enlarge its domain with `Piecewise` in the following way:

```
mydata={{0.0000255111, 3.48715}, {0.0000497289, 3.48715}, {0.0000760032, 
  3.68666}, {0.000101685, 4.13102}, {0.000127819, 
  4.8565}, {0.000160668, 5.89031}, {0.000199871, 
  7.03839}, {0.000251762, 8.11573}, {0.000510537, 
  10.1906}, {0.000759276, 10.6694}, {0.00131224, 
  10.8689}, {0.00205196, 10.8689}, {0.0039503, 10.8689}, {0.00586421, 
  10.8939}, {0.00936259, 10.9687}, {0.0121416, 11.0684}, {0.0157784, 
  11.1682}, {0.0214132, 11.7097}, {0.0269805, 12.465}, {0.0329414, 
  13.1633}, {0.0438442, 14.3354}, {0.0542594, 15.1783}, {0.0848459, 
  16.9373}, {0.105548, 18.4687}, {0.12379, 20.6365}, {0.132191, 
  22.4652}, {0.142875, 25.3083}, {0.15004, 27.8604}, {0.159849, 
  31.6752}, {0.167637, 34.0867}, {0.174909, 36.6097}, {0.180292, 
  39.116}, {0.187948, 41.5931}, {0.199271, 43.9}, {0.209739, 
  46.4811}, {0.225458, 48.9749}, {0.249185, 51.8844}, {0.270797, 
  54.2419}, {0.294283, 56.4441}, {0.320717, 58.4715}, {0.355922, 
  60.696}, {0.399908, 62.9903}, {0.468012, 65.264}, {0.537837, 
  67.6701}, {0.651061, 70.2674}, {0.770893, 72.5252}, {0.936818, 
  74.8075}, {1.12961, 76.9189}, {1.39071, 79.1248}, {1.74812, 
  80.9415}, {2.24823, 82.6618}, {2.80845, 83.7092}, {3.61942, 
  84.6744}, {4.4099, 85.2231}, {5.69251, 85.5709}, {7.33036, 
  85.8964}, {10.4519, 86.1783}, {13.1381, 86.691}, {16.5145, 
  87.616}, {20.7588, 88.7737}, {26.0938, 90.4665}, {31.4639, 
  92.2634}, {37.1584, 94.0748}, {44.8055, 96.3118}, {54.0264, 
  98.3997}, {66.5137, 100.666}, {83.6078, 102.479}, {105.095, 
  103.924}, {140.871, 105.274}, {176.744, 105.871}, {222.168, 
  106.231}, {279.265, 106.498}, {351.037, 106.642}, {441.253, 
  106.639}, {554.656, 106.842}, {697.203, 106.887}, {870.332, 
  106.902}, {1101.62, 106.932}, {1384.73, 106.932}, {1740.61, 
  106.932}, {2187.95, 106.932}, {2750.26, 106.932}, {3457.08, 
  106.932}, {4345.55, 106.932}, {5462.36, 106.932}, {6866.2, 
  106.932}, {8630.82, 106.932}, {10393.3, 106.932}, {12043.3, 
  106.932}};

myfun=Interpolation[mydata];
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{myfun[x], x <= 1000}, {myfun[1000], x > 1000}}];
```

Now, I want to find a new function `T[t]` that satisfies this differential equation, where $f(T)$ is the function `f` defined with the list of data.

$$\dfrac{1}{T}\dfrac{dT}{dt}=-\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}\frac{T}{f(T)}\frac{df(T)}{dT}}$$

This is what I've done (the initial conditions should be reasonable for the problem I am tackling):

```
diffeq={T[t]'/T[t]==-1/(1+0.3*T[t]/f[T[t]]*f[T[t]]')};
NDSolve=[diffeq,T[-40]==10^10,T,{t,-40,0}];
```

My code fails at finding the solution and I suspect that the problem resides in how I write the differential equation. I think that nesting the function `T[t]` that I want to find inside another function `f[T]` (and also making a derivative of `f`) drives Mathematica crazy.

How can I manage this task?

Thank you for your help!

---

**Update, after the answer of Petrini**

His method seems to work, but the error one receives is of the type

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

I have noticed that the function `f` has some serious smoothness problems, a glitch of `Interpolation`.
Its shape is like this:

[image: Graph of the function]

but when you zoom in several intervals, like `10^-3,10^-2` you get this wiggling behaviour, whereas the data show a decreasing one, without oscillating.

[image: function zoomed]

The real problem (linked to the previous one I suppose) regards the derivative function, because if I plot `f'[x]` I get something that is a complete mess:

[image: derivative of function]

Hence, the 1/0 error should rise from here.

So maybe the problem now is more like

**How do you get rid of that problematic behaviour of the function and its derivative?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment versus an answer, but you can improve your interpolation by performing it on log-log transformed.  If you `ListPlot` `mydata`, you will see that much of the data is up against the `x=0` axis.

```
ListPlot[mydata]
```

[image: List Plot of mydata]

Since your data looks much nicer and spread out on a `ListLogLogPlot`, you can perform the interpolation on Log-Log transformed data as shown:

```
lmyfun = Interpolation[Log@mydata];
lf[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Exp@lmyfun[Log[x]], x <= 1000}, {Exp@lmyfun[Log[1000]], 
     x > 1000}}];
```

Now, the interpolation is better behaved in the region you showed although you still have some discontinuities.

```
Show[{LogLogPlot[{f[x], lf[x]}, {x, 0.001, 0.01}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.001, 0.01}, {10.6, 10.9}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"original", "log transformed"}], 
  ListLogLogPlot[mydata]}]
```

[image: Log transformed plot]

## Update to Include `BSplineFunction`

`Interpolation` will create a continuous function that passes through each interpolated point, but there is no guarantee that the derivatives will be continuous.  As @Petrini stated in the comments, you may want to try fitting to have continuous derivatives.  Fitting will not necessarily pass through data points, but it should have derivatives that are continuous up to a specified order.  I will show an example using `BSPlineFunction` where I create a fit, then I resample with many points to create a smoother interpolation.

```
bsf = BSplineFunction[Log@mydata];
resampleddata = bsf[#] & /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 2000];
lbsmyfun = Interpolation[resampleddata];
lbsf[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Exp@lbsmyfun[Log[x]], 
     x <= 1000}, {Exp@lbsmyfun[Log[1000]], x > 1000}}];
Show[{LogLogPlot[{f[x], lf[x], lbsf[x]}, {x, 0.0001, 0.01}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.001, 0.01}, {10.5, 10.9}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"original", "log transformed", "bspline"}], 
  ListLogLogPlot[mydata]}]
```

[image: BSpline Fit]

Now, the derivatives are finite and positive so they show up on a log log plot without the breaks the OP observed.

```
LogLogPlot[lbsf'[x], {x, 0.0001, 1000}]
```

[image: Derivative Plot]

## Update 2: Eliminate Piecewise Function by Padding Data

You have a division by zero warning due to the Piecewise function having a discontinuous derivative and extrapolation warnings due to `mydata` not going to low enough T values.  You can eliminate these warnings by padding both ends by the initial and final values, respectively.  You will need to make a decision whether it is valid to do so in this case.

```
mydata2 = 
  Table[{0.0000255111/2^(11 - i), 3.48715}, {i, 1, 10}]~Join~mydata~
   Join~Table[{12043.3 2^i, 106.932`}, {i, 1, 20}];
bsf = BSplineFunction[Log@mydata2];
resampleddata = bsf[#] & /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 4000];
lbsmyfun = Interpolation[resampleddata];
Plot[lbsmyfun[x], {x, -17, 23}]
lbsf[x_] := Exp@lbsmyfun[Log[x]]
diffeq = {T'[t]/T[t] == -1/(1 + (1/3)*T[t]/lbsf[T[t]]*lbsf'[T[t]])};
boundary = {T[-40] == 10^10};
odeqs = diffeq~Join~boundary;
tsol = NDSolveValue[odeqs, T, {t, -40, 0}];
LogPlot[tsol[t], {t, -40, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Padded interpolation function]

Comment: This is useful, thank you. However, there still remain some discontinuities... It sounds really crazy that Mathematica is not able to give a simple interpolation, without those sharp oscillations!

Comment: I added a `BSplineFunction` fit example.  As suggested by @Petrini, you can have continuous derivatives with a fit.  `Interpolation` goes through every point, but the derivatives may not be continuous.

Comment: Oh, very nice update! However, if I try to solve the differential equation I still obtain the 1/0 error. Damn... where does it come from? If I try with a domain like `{-40,-25}` it does not complain. But already with `{-40,-20}` I get the error...

Comment: If you perform a `FindRoot` where `T=1000`, then you will see it occurs at `t=-23.8819`.  Your `Piecewise` function does not have a continuous derivative @T=1000.  You probably could pad your data out to 10^10 and eliminate the `Piecewise` function.

Comment: Ok, are you saying that prolonging the data imposing the continuity of the function in `T=1000` makes it sharp? Do you have any other idea about how to smoothly pad the data? Than you!

Comment: Piecewise functions do not have defined derivatives at their corner points.  There is also an extrapolation warning due to mydata not going to low enough T values.  I added an example that pads both ends of mydata.  You will need to decide if it is appropriate to do so for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have thought about a solution of this kind...

Answer (score 1):

I could get some results by defining *before* the my data block:

```
diffeq = {T'[t]/T[t] == -1/(1 + (1/3)*T[t]/f[T[t]]*f'[T[t]])}
boundary = {T[-40] == 10^10}
odeqs = diffeq~Join~boundary
```

Where I took freedom to change 0.3 to (1/3), since they're not equal and your equation seems to use the latter.

And then using after defining f[x_]:

```
sol = NDSolve[odeqs, T, {t, -40, 0}];
Plot[Evaluate[{T[t] /. sol}], {t, -40, 0}]
```

But it found 1/0 values and supressed some of the evaluation. I hope it is of any help.

Comment: Interesting! I get the 1/0 error too and maybe I know where the problem is, I post an update of the question!

Comment: Maybe you could use fitting, instead of interpolation of the data. Therefore you can guarantee the smoothness of the derivative

Comment: Do you have any theoretical model for the data? You can fit into that